# MySQL INSERT INTO statement giving ERROR CODE 1062

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a F1 database and I'm trying to insert the team principal's name (from Principals table) into the Teams table, but for some reason it won't work. I'm not sure if my insert into statement is wrong, but I can't see why it would be. The code is below

---

```
CREATE TABLE Teams (
Team_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Driver_1 INT NULL, 
Driver_2 INT NULL, 
Nation VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Seasons INT NOT NULL, 
No_Titles INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
Principal VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (Team_Name));

CREATE TABLE Principals (
Principal_No INT NOT NULL, 
Principal_Name VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
Team VARCHAR(30) NULL, 
Age INT NOT NULL, 
Nationality VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
Seasons INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
PRIMARY KEY (Principal_No), 
FOREIGN KEY (Team) REFERENCES Teams(Team_Name));
```

Here's the insert statement. The Principals table has already been populated with the principal names and their corresponding teams

```
INSERT INTO Teams (Principal) 
SELECT Principal_Name 
FROM Principals 
WHERE Team IN(
    SELECT Team_Name 
    FROM Teams);
```

Comment: Is auto increment of primary key working?

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I'm new to SQL. So I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. "`but for some reason it won't work`" this should be more specific. What was (is) the sample data you used and what was the expected output? Was there any error output or messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your INSERT statement

```
INSERT INTO Teams (Principal) 
--                 ^
```

you're only inserting a value for the field `Principal` into the table `Teams`. But the `Teams` table has other fields as well... not inserting values into them will default them to NULL. This will lead to a contradiction in the arguments. In your `Teams` table:

```
Team_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
Nation VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
Seasons INT NOT NULL
```

these fields, by definition, can't be NULL. But since no values are inserted with the INSERT statement, these will default to NULL, clashing with the definition and causing an error.

You may want to consider setting default values for the above fields **or**  modifying your INSERT statement to accommodate those fields.

```
INSERT INTO Teams (Principal, Team_Name, Nation, Seasons)
SELECT 
    -- four columns ...
```

Comment: Ahh I see now. Thanks a lot! I appreciate it

Comment: @Clank when an answer worked for you; you can consider marking it as accepted answer. Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement tries to assign null values to columns that have 'not null' property. Check these columns 'not null' -> false   or  assign default value or define values in your insert statement. I hope this help

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But where exactly does it try to assign null values? All my values for Principal are set to their proper names, so should it not only be assigning initialised values?

Comment: INSERT INTO Teams (Principal)   this expression assign to only column  'principal' and tries to assign NULL value to others.

Comment: Is there a way of inserting just Principals without trying to insert NULL everywhere else?

Comment: when a row is inserted, it is inserted with all columns of that table. You define (in insert statement)  specific value, or not define(in insert statement) and let it use its default value already defined in table construction or not define(in insert statement) and let it to be NULL(if columns 'NOT NULL' property is not checked )